# Adding/Appending Dynamic Div with Database (SQL) Select Box on Button click and inserting those values to dabase

Tags: javascript, php, sql, jquery

I need to add a dynamic div with a database list box on button click and allow the user to chose the values and insert the same to database on submit button click.

Please see the code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="data1" value="abc" />
</td>
<td>
    <button type="button" onClick="addRow(this)">Add</button>
</td>
```

```
function addRow(btn) {

$.post("cars.php",function(data){

$(btn).closest('table').append(data);

   });
}


$a = mysql_query("select * from cars");

echo '<tr><td><select>';

while($b = mysql_fetch_array($a)) {

echo '<option value="'.$b['id'].'">'.$b['brand'].'</option>';

}

echo '</select></td></td>';
```

till here it is working fine (thanks for the support sofar), now i need to insert the values to SQL database Table . could you please help

Thanks 
Jeena

Comment: you want to insert select value?

Comment: Yea. user will select the values and click submit button, at that time selected values need to be send to SQL Database Table

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing now?..

Comment: i am not sure how to insert those values (not getting inserted), since i am appending multiple times

Comment: Post your `insert` code..